# Cascading look up field in project server

Tags: 2013, project-server, cascading

I need to add to look up fields in project page , to be cascaded

eg : once select project type filter all projects that belong to this type in another look up field

[image]

Any help please ?

Comment: You might find plenty of helpful existing questions & answer by going through the tag [tag:cascading].

Comment: Thank you , could you help me with example please ?